# Ruby on Rails Model association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am trying to make an application using Rails 3.2.14, but I can't wrap my head around the model associations that I have built so far. I have four models which are interconnected to give desired result but so far it hasn't been working.

- `Job` with fields: `user_id`, `title`
- `Jobapplication` with fields: `job_id`, `user_id`, `isrefused`
- `Resume` with fields: `user_id`, `profession`

I am trying to extract all the jobs which a particular user has applied for using the `jobapplication` model in an instance variable for the view.

All tables containing foreign keys have `belong_to` associations along with `has_many` at the other end.

So far, I have tried like this in the controller:

```
def applied job
  @jobapplications = Jobapplication.where('user_id = ?', current_user.id)
  @jobs            = @jobapplications.jobs
end
```

The purpose is to find jobs for which the user has put in application for.

Should I redesign the models association?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accessors can be greatly simplified if you write your model associations like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs                  # jobs posted
  has_many :job_applications      # job applications posted
  has_many :applied_jobs, through => :job_applications, :source => :job  # jobs applied for
  has_one :resume
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :job_applications
  has_many :applicants, :through => :job_applications, :source => :user   # applicants for this job
  has_many :applicant_resumes, :through => :job_applications, :source => :resume
end

class JobApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
  has_one :resume, :through => :user  # the resume for the application
end

class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now you can easily find the jobs a user applied for:

```
current_user.applied_jobs
```

Or all the applicants (users applying) for a specific job:

```
@job.applicants
```

And you can see a user's resume:

```
current_user.resume
```

Or an application's resume:

```
@job_application.resume
```

Or all resumes for those applying for a specific job:

```
@job.applicant_resumes
```

Comment: Perfect. I'll take this discussion a bit further. How to integrate a resume table into that as well. I have a separate resume table which gives user's profile information. resume belong_to user and user has_one resume. From employer(user with jobs) perspective how we can search for resumes on a a given jobapplication.

Comment: If I'm correct in my understanding, the job_application.user is the user applying for the job.  If so, only one resume can be attached to a JobApplication.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

This looks okay:

```
@jobapplications = Jobapplication.where("user_id =?", current_user.id)
```

but not sure about this:

```
@jobs = @jobapplications.jobs
```

What's the `jobs` method?

try this:

```
#some_controller.rb

def applied_job #note the underscore!
  @jobapplications = Jobapplication.where("user_id =?", current_user.id)
end
```

and in the view

```
<% @jobapplications.each do |application| %>
  #list applications here
<% end %>
```

Comment: This would work, although subject to N+1 queries.  You could add `includes` to get around this, but it's unnecessarily messy when you can simply write the necessary ActiveRecord associations.

Comment: your way is much nicer :) +1

Comment: Dax I like the way worked through this, even if it's not the cleanest answer. I gave you both +1 because I like both of your answers.